# Not logging in? No value for login error?

Tags: java, php, android

the api login.php is correct but some problem in java code in android studio but not understanding the problem?need help in code?

I have tried my method but it dosen't solve my problem.

this is my login.php code.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
require_once 'uconnection.php';

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

if (!$data) {
    $result['success'] = "0";
    $result['message'] = "Login payload missing. Send email and password in the request header.";
    echo json_encode($result);

    mysqli_close($conn);
} else {
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        $email = $data->email;
        $password = $data->password;
        if ($email != null && $password != null) {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='" . $email . "' AND password='" . $password . "' ";

            $response = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

            // var_dump($response);
            // echo $response->num_rows;
            // echo "--";
            // echo mysqli_num_rows($response);
            // echo "--";

            $result = array();
            $result['login'] = array();

            // echo "OUTSIDE";
            if (mysqli_num_rows($response) > 0) {

                // echo "Found";

                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($response);
                print_r($row);
                // echo $row["password"];

                if ($email == $row["email"] && $password == $row["password"]) {

                    // echo "VERIFIED";

                    $index['firstname'] = $row['firstname'];
                    $index['email'] = $row['email'];
                    $index['id'] = $row['id'];

                    array_push($result['login'], $index);

                    $result['success'] = "1";
                    $result['message'] = "success";
                    echo json_encode($result);

                    mysqli_close($conn);

                } else {

                    $result['success'] = "0";
                    $result['message'] = "error";
                    echo json_encode($result);

                    mysqli_close($conn);

                }
            } else {
                $result['success'] = "0";
                $result['message'] = "Incorrect username and/or password";
                echo json_encode($result);

                mysqli_close($conn);

            }
        } else {
            if ($email == null) {
                $result['success'] = "0";
                $result['message'] = "email missing";
                echo json_encode($result);

                mysqli_close($conn);
            }

            if ($password == null) {
                $result['success'] = "0";
                $result['message'] = "password missing";
                echo json_encode($result);

                mysqli_close($conn);
            }
        }
    } else {
        $result['success'] = "0";
        $result['message'] = "only POST request possbile";
        echo json_encode($result);

        mysqli_close($conn);
    }
}
```

And this is android java login class code.

```
private EditText emailid,password;
    private Button buttonlogin,buttonregister1;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    String emailid_login, password_login;

    private static String URL_LOGIN = "http://192.168.68.74:80/loginregistervollyphp/login.php";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        emailid = findViewById(R.id.etxt_email);
        password = findViewById(R.id.etxt_password);
        buttonlogin = findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        buttonregister1 = findViewById(R.id.btn_register);

        buttonregister1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i1 = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i1);
                finish();
            }
        });

        buttonlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                emailid_login = emailid.getText().toString().trim();
                password_login = password.getText().toString().trim();

                if (!emailid_login.isEmpty() && !password_login.isEmpty()){
                    login(emailid_login,password_login);
                }
                else {
                    emailid.setError("Please insert Email id");
                    password.setError("Please insert Password");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void displayLoader() {
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loging In... Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    private void login(final String email, final String password){
        displayLoader();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,URL_LOGIN,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    String success = jsonObject.getString("success");
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("login");
                    Log.d("LOGINSUCCESS", String.valueOf(jsonObject));

                    if (!success.equals("0")){

                            String email2 = jsonObject.getString("email").trim();
                            String fname = jsonObject.getString("firstname").trim();

                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,UserDashboard.class);
                            intent.putExtra("email",email2);
                            intent.putExtra("firstname",fname);
                            startActivity(intent);
                    }else if (success.equals("0")){
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error! Logging In", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error Loging in: "+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error Loging in: "
                                +error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("email",email);
                params.put("password",password);
                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }
```

Comment: This error appears on android app "Error! logging in". The second success is executed on  the on response section area .

Comment: Are you sure that you're using java and not javascript?

Comment: I am using java in android studio man and php in the API.I have problem in code in android studio java code. login on response.The app is returning 0 from success object.

Comment: In the PHP what do you get if you do a var_dump() on the JSON data?

Comment: {"success":"0","message":"Login payload missing. Send email and password in the request header."}. I am getting this on var_dump($data) on else part of php code.

Comment: Have you tried to change `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` to `GET` then directly visit the page in your browser to ensure it is working as per expected? It appears you're not sending the correct data in your header.